# How to mount an emergency switch

Tags: switches

I have this emergency switch that I need to mount on a control cabinet. I googled but cannot find any tutorial or picture on how this switch supposed to be mounted.

Am I supposed to mount the whole thing outside the enclosure? But then the whole switch (B) will protrude too much and looks ugly aesthetically. Am I suppose to detach A from the switch where A is outside of the enclosure and the rest hide inside the enclosure? But it requires me to disassemble the internal switch plastic parts to do that.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a picture of teh whole switch, and manufacturer's name and part number.

Comment: It's unclear what "the enclosure" means.   The shown switch can be mounted to a brick wall or steel girder; anywhere that is convenient in an emergency is the right location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That switch looks like it's meant to be attached to a wiring conduit. It isn't designed for the application you have in mind.

What you're looking for is a "panel mount" emergency stop switch. Search for a part using these keywords and you'll find something more appropriate.

Comment: Just to elaborate a little, it looks as though that circular section is to be punched/drilled out to allow the conduit to fit. I suspect there's screwholes in the back plane of the grey housing.

Answer (score 2):

It is used in external remote wiring conduit.
 If you need to use it, you can mount as below.
Refer the below picture .
[image]
I think so too that You should use emergency stop switch for Panel mount